# ServletOutputStream.write throws index out of bounds sometimes

Tags: java, servlets, outputstream

I am having a problem which I cannot reproduce consistently. I read a file and write the contents of that file to ServletOutputStream.

```
                        byte[] buff = new byte[65536];

                        int bytesRead = dataStream.read(buff);
                        response.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, bytesRead);
```

I noticed the some files (smaller than 20KBs) throw IndexOutofBoundsException when writing to the outputstream sometimes but at other times, everything works just find. By that I mean, no IndexOutOfBoundsException is reported.

Here is the stack trace that I get:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:331)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:392)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:381)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:88)
        at com.abc.web.DeliverData.serviceRequest(DeliverData.java:101)
```

Line 101 in my code is:
           response.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, bytesRead);

Any ideas why the problem is not reported consistently even if testing with the same files?

Answer (score 6):

`inputStream.read(..)` can return `-1`. I'd suggest using [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-2.0/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from commons-io: `IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream)`. For the record, it is implemented as follows:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int n = 0;
while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
   output.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bozho. I see your point but in my logs, I print the size of the file which is about to be read and written to the outputstream. So that means that the file is accessible. Don't you think? I will look into IOUtils.copy also. Thanks again

Comment: Are you suggesting that my bytearray should not be more than 4096? Because in my case, it is 65536? Or you just wanted to show me the correct way of implementing read/write?

Comment: @user305210 it is the buffer they use at apache :) you can try a different buffer size.